# i have a very simple problem web page but my articles doesn't work as i want

Tags: javascript, html, css

could someone help with this?
i have four articles and i want them to be organized like this:

```
                           first one 
second one                 third one                    fourth one
```

but i don't understand what is the problem??

```
body {
    background-color: #edefee;
    font-family: serif;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

header > img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

section {
    display: flex;
}

article {
    flex: 1;
}

footer {
    display: flex;
}

footer div {
    flex: 1;
}
```

my problem for the articles [image: this is the result i want]

could someone help with this?
i want this result and this is my code for css part

Comment: Post your HTML too please. We need a [mcve]

Comment: this is my html code:

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like https://grid.layoutit.com/ to draw this using grid.
something like this :)

```
.container {
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr; 
  gap: 0px 0px; 
  grid-template-areas: 
    ". a1 ."
    "a2 a3 a4"; 
}
.a1 { grid-area: a1; }
.a2 { grid-area: a2; }
.a3 { grid-area: a3; }
.a4 { grid-area: a4; }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is ny html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="author" content="">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <img src="logos/logo3.png" alt="" width="300px" height="100px">
</header>



<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Book</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>



<main>
    <section>
        <article class="art-fle">
            <h1>Header 1</h1>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat 
corporis voluptate vel ab consectetur repudiandae sunt accusantium. 
Perspiciatis, minima voluptatem!</p>
        </article>
    </section>
    <section>
        <article class="art-fle">
            <h2>Header 2</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
Similique, enim ad architecto necessitatibus consectetur tempora.</p>
        </article>
    </section>
    <section>
        <article class="art-fle">
            <h2>Header 3</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, 
autem! Modi voluptate officia facere voluptatibus!</p>
        </article>
    </section>
    <section>
        <article class="art-fle">
            <h2>Header 4</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
Perferendis, veniam nam! Dicta dolorum officiis quas?</p>
        </article>
    </section>
</main>

<footer>
    <div>
        <img src="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Copyright Little Lemon</p>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want specifically? please give me more details to allow me help you precisely as I see your code and i didn't fine any problem in HTML syntax.

Comment: What do you want specifically? please give me more details to allow me help you precisely as I see your code and i didn't fine any problem in HTML syntax.